# Source to download SharePoint 2010 themes

Tags: 2010, theme

Is there a good source to download free SharePoint Themes (.thmx) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't find a site which hosts only SharePoint 2010 themes. Two good themese are here http://www.topsharepoint.com/themes

Answer (score 2):

Not free. http://tuning.bind.pt/Sharepoint-Themes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a vast quantity of web designs out there, but they are not designed for SharePoint. However, what you can do is render a page in SharePoint that will support some of these themes. So for example if you render HTML that looks like the CSS Garden HTML template you have a starting point to use their themes. But it's not going to be easy. Begin with a simplified [starter master page](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/), which is a normal practice for developing Internet sites on SharePoint anyway.

You are probably not going to get your HTML spot on without either using control adaptors and other techniques. So it is more likely that you will end up adapting the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Themes can be created in PowerPoint, exported, and imported into Sharepoint.  This will allow you to create styles, color palletes and fonts appropriate to your organization's style guides.

Comment: Creating theme from scratch is too cumbersome... especially colors for different things

Comment: Too cumbersome, that's the first I've heard that mentioned.